# How to get the current state of a famo.us Surface?

Tags: famo.us

I need to determine the position of a specific surface, and normally I would use `getTransform()` to gain access to the x,y,z properties of the translate modifier.  Unfortunately, according to the famo.us documentation, Modifier's `getTransform()` method is [deprecated](http://famo.us/docs/api/latest/core/Modifier).

My intent is to use those values to position another surface relative to those coordinates using `transitionableTransform.setTranslate()`

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Famo.us wants the developer to think in terms of updating the 3D transformation outside of your modifier and having the modifier access these values through the `transitionable` values being returned.  Actually a good practice once you understand the core of the framework.

The Examples below show a simple way of doing this in two different instances.

**Remember:** The translate value returned is relative to the origin and align of the modifier, so you will be getting a position [x, y, z] relative to the starting position `[0,0,0]`. Both surfaces would need to have the same tree node origin or relative position.

#### Example 1: Sets Transform after final transition of dependent Surface

Gets the transform from a `TransitionableTransform` based on the main surface `TransitionableTransform`.

```js
define('main', function(require, exports, module) {
  var Engine = require("famous/core/Engine");
  var Surface = require("famous/core/Surface");
  var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');
  var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
  var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
  var TransitionableTransform = require('famous/transitions/TransitionableTransform');

  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
  mainContext.setPerspective(1000);
  
  var surface = new Surface({
    content: 'Click to Transition',
    properties: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)',
      textAlign: 'center'
    }
  });
  surface._trans = new TransitionableTransform();
  surface._mod = new Modifier({
    origin: [0.5, 0],
    align: [0.5, 0],
    size: [200, 200],
    transform: surface._trans
  });

  var surfaceFollower = new Surface({
    content: 'F o l l o w e r',
    properties: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5)',
      fontSize: '1em'
    }
  });
  surfaceFollower._trans = new TransitionableTransform();
  surfaceFollower._mod = new Modifier({
    origin: [0.5, 0],
    align: [0.5, 0],
    size: [12, 200],
    transform: surfaceFollower._trans
  });
  
  mainContext.add(surface._mod).add(surface);
  mainContext.add(surfaceFollower._mod).add(surfaceFollower);

  function followSurface() {
    //var translate = surface._trans.translate.get(); // returns [x, y, z]
    //var pos = [translate[0]+106,translate[1],translate[2]];
    var translate = surface._trans.get(); // returns 3D transform matrix
    var pos = [translate[12]+106,translate[13],translate[14]];
      surfaceFollower._trans.setTranslate(pos , {duration: 300});
  }
  surface.on('click', function() {
    var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    if (this.randomly)
      this._trans.setTranslate([0, 0, 0], {duration: 300}, followSurface);
    else
      this._trans.setTranslate([randomX, randomY, 0], {duration: 300}, followSurface);
    
    this.randomly = !this.randomly;
  });

  
  
  followSurface();
});

// Start Main App
require(['main']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.css" />

<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.min.js"></script>
```

#### Example 2: Sets Transform from a function on every tick

Returning a translation transform based on the dependent Surface position.

```js
  surfaceFollower._mod = new Modifier({
    origin: [0.5, 0],
    align: [0.5, 0],
    size: [12, 200],
    transform: followSurface
  });
  function followSurface(e) {
    var translate = surface._trans.get();
    return Transform.translate(translate[12]+106,translate[13],translate[14]);
  }
```

```js
define('main', function(require, exports, module) {
  var Engine = require("famous/core/Engine");
  var Surface = require("famous/core/Surface");
  var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');
  var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
  var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
  var TransitionableTransform = require('famous/transitions/TransitionableTransform');

  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
  mainContext.setPerspective(1000);
  
  var surface = new Surface({
    content: 'Click to Transition',
    properties: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)',
      textAlign: 'center'
    }
  });
  surface._trans = new TransitionableTransform();
  surface._mod = new Modifier({
    origin: [0.5, 0],
    align: [0.5, 0],
    size: [200, 200],
    transform: surface._trans
  });

  var surfaceFollower = new Surface({
    content: 'F o l l o w e r',
    properties: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5)',
      fontSize: '1em'
    }
  });
  surfaceFollower._mod = new Modifier({
    origin: [0.5, 0],
    align: [0.5, 0],
    size: [12, 200],
    transform: followSurface
  });
  
  mainContext.add(surface._mod).add(surface);
  mainContext.add(surfaceFollower._mod).add(surfaceFollower);

  function followSurface(e) {
    //var translate = surface._trans.translate.get(); // returns [x,y,z]
    //return Transform.translate(translate[0]+106,translate[1],translate[2]);
    var translate = surface._trans.get();
    return Transform.translate(translate[12]+106,translate[13],translate[14]);
  }
  surface.on('click', function() {
    var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    if (this.randomly)
      this._trans.setTranslate([0, 0, 0], {duration: 300});
    else
      this._trans.setTranslate([randomX, randomY, 0], {duration: 300});
    
    this.randomly = !this.randomly;
  });
});

// Start Main App
require(['main']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.css" />

<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.min.js"></script>
```